# React + Axios - Don't get answer (Probably because of promise..?)

Tags: javascript, reactjs, axios

I'm trying to build a react application and with axios and it doesn't work as I expect... I guess its async Problem, that my return doesn't wait for the call to be finished...

The structure of my files may seem a bit weird, but I need to do it like that (not allowed to change it...)...

My Component: (It will always console log "not set"

```
import * as api from '../../services/home/HomeController';
.......
// Some other stuff in this section
.......
  componentDidMount() {
    var result = api.getAll();
    this.setState({
      data1: result
    });
  }
  ..........
render() {
  if(this.state.data1 === undefined) {
    console.log("not set");
  }
  else {
    console.log(this.state.data1);
  }
}
```

My HomeController:

```
import { fetchData } from '../axios/axios';

export const getAll = () => {
  return fetchData('https://myAPIUrl'); //removed the correct URL
};
```

The axios function:
import axios from 'axios';

```
export const fetchData = (url) => {
  axios.get(url)
    .then(res => {
      console.log("Axios returning result...");
      //console.log(res.data); //When I un-comment this line, I get the result logged in the console
      return res.data;
    });
}
```

So as you see, the result gets logged in the console in the axios component, since this function hat a promise and wait the call to be finished. But I guess the return on HomeController doesn't do that, I am right?

Pretty new to JS, kinda confusing this whole ASYNC thing... What would be the best solution for my problem?

Thank you for your help ! :)

Comment: Do a console.log(result); after var result = api.getAll(); and check what its returning

Comment: @KiranKumar undefined

Comment: You can use async/await https://medium.com/@kkomaz/react-to-async-await-553c43f243e2

Comment: `export const fetchData = (url) => {
  return axios.get(url)` (return the promise from fetchData) and `api.getAll().then(result=>this.setState(...` Wait for promise to resolve and set state with the result.